# Overloaded cast operator inheritance (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

The following code compiles in XCode, but not in VS2008/VS2010 (error: Ambiguous user-defined conversion). If I use a function instead of cast operator, it complies without errors.  Is it a VS bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{

public:

    virtual operator int() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class B : public virtual A
{

public:

    virtual operator int() const
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

class C : public virtual A, public virtual B
{

public:

};

int main()
{

    C c;

    int i = (int)c;

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because the compiler finds it can do things in different manners, since casting is implicit, the compiler has to choose "the right way".

Starting with your case: the compiler can't really do something like

```
(int) c;
```

It doesn't know how, but it can cast c into something that it does know how to cast into int, but this leaves two options:

```
(int) A(c);
(int) B(c);
```

Both equally valid and very diferent! There is no way to know which to implement. Actually you might even find a problem if you have a variable b of type B, since you can cast two ways:

```
(int) b;
(int) A(b);
```

If the compiler chose one way, you'd have no idea which, and diferent compilers could choose different options!
So what are some solutions:

1. Make a casts from B to A, C to B and C to A explicit. Then create a
   cast function that first casts this into the class you want, and
   then casts that to int. This though will not work with visual
   studio, which you are using, so this will not work for your case.
2. Make the B class protected, but since you want C to be casted as B, this doesn't work. 
   Because of the issue in casting B into an int, you can't just make A protected.
3. Define the cast operation in A, but make it call a virtual function, which B
   overrides. That way there is only one cast operation, defined in A,
   no ambiguos case.

I think the 3rd option is the best in your case, it'd look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{

protected:

    virtual int _int_cast() const
    {
       return 1;
    }

public:

    operator int() const
    {
        return this->_int_cast();
    }
};

class B : public virtual A
{

protected:

    virtual int _int_cast() const
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

class C : public virtual A, public virtual B
{

public:

};

int main()
{

    C c;

    int i = (int)c;

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically: don't reimplement overloaded casts from classes you inherit, assume that it has to first convert to the base class. Also watch out for overloaded casts that are very similiar, for example, you could convert into an int, and then a const int, or just cast into const int directly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps getting a warning in xcode? I was not able to check the code in xcode, but I was able to in VS2010 and I got one warning, and one error.

Warning:

`main.cpp(30): warning C4250: 'C' : inherits 'B::B::operator int' via dominance`
`main.cpp(19) : see declaration of 'B::operator int'`

Error:

`main.cpp(37): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'C' to 'int'`

The warning may help explain the error in your case. The warning is described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b3sy7ae%28v=vs.80%29.aspx , which I suggest you read over.

As for the error, well, I can not say for 100% certainty yet other than maybe the inheritance causing an issue. If you define the operator int for c, it will compile.